# FreeBSD kernel nat or natd?

Tags: freebsd, firewall

As I notice more often with FreeBSD, there are always plenty of ways that lead to some specific goal.

After figuring out which firewall I wanted (I choose ipfw) I now am completely insecure about which way to do Network Address Translation (NAT).

As I have discovered now, there are two ways to to NAT, I could use the kernel space `ipfw nat` or I could use the userspace `natd`.

The  only one of these described in the FreeBSD handbook is [`natd`](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/network-natd.html).

What I would like to know is what the main differences are between these? Which one is more popular.

Off course I would also like to be able to fish, so how I can find out these differences in the manuals/handbooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ipfw nat` is generally preferable, since it runs in kernel-space and consumes less CPU than divert+`natd`. But `natd` still can be useful if you need to dynamically add rules for FTP connections (look for `-punch_fw` option in `natd(8)`). Handbook page is badly outdated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [you're not alone (mailing list thread on the issue)](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.os.freebsd.questions/218777).

From it, I gathered that `natd` apparently was the only choice up to FreeBSD 7.x and that the handbook page you referenced probably needs revision ([see this post](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.os.freebsd.questions/218783)), and in-kernel NAT is possibly faster.

Apart from that, both solutions still seem fine (both are present in a standard FreeBSD installation, after all) and the usual kernelspace/userspace arguments apply...not the most satisfactory answer, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't even know there was a kernel nat (natd replacement) until tonight. My natd is using stupid amounts of cpu cycles, even when there is hardly any traffic. It seems that you need to carefully control what type of packets go through natd to avoid this high cpu. And it depends of the nature of your environment as to what ipfw rules are best to avoid unwanted traffic being diverted to natd.

I can't find a simple ruleset that doesn't cause problems for me. I suspect it's because I have jails running on LAN IPs, and that generates traffic through natd. So, i'm now off to learn ipfw + kernel nat.

The handbook really just needs to mention this, even a one-liner would be enough to start with.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer, unless you are actually attempting to answer the posted question.